# Application.Current.Windows.Cast<Window>() returns null

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to access some controls (ScrollViewer and Grid) from another window. I tried this:

```
var reportW = Application.Current.Windows.Cast<Window>().SingleOrDefault(window => window is ReportWindow) as ReportWindow;
ScrollViewer myScrollViewer = reportW.testScrollViewer;
Grid myGrid = reportW.Grd;
```

Problem is that reportW is allways `null`. Is something wrong with my approach and is there any other way to access controls from another window?

Comment: None of your windows are of type `ReportWindow`.  Note that almost all uses of this pattern are poor design.  Rather than looking through all open windows for windows of a given type you should be communicating with more direct relationships between the windows.  Odds are in a case like this that type should be either returning a value or firing an event such that the window can update itself based on the information given to it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
ReportWindow reportW = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<ReportWindow>().
SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Still the same problem. I just can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: I would agree with @Servy that if this line above returns `null`, then you have no `Window`s of type `ReportWindow` open. Are you sure that `ReportWindow` is the correct type?

Comment: Ok well I found the solution but didn't realize that my window must be opened. So this approach will defineatly will not work. But I need to access the control of my window without opening it. Is this possible??

Comment: Hey I found the solution to load window without showing it. Thank you for the tip that my window must be opened to use this line of the code.